# Sliding animation orientation from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making slideshow of forms and it is working fine. Here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwWZpV).

As you can see if I click those dots, it will open another form but the transition happens from left to right. I wanted to make that transition from top to bottom. Is this possible to do? I am not able to figure out how we can make the transition happen from top to bottom if I click those dots. You can play around with my codepen link.

Below is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides" class="container-fluid" >
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>  

<a href="#" class="arrow slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class=" arrow slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>




    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am using SlideJS plugin here but looks like they don't allow this animation or maybe I am wrong. Is there any other way by which I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlidesJS doesn't seem to have vertical slide option. I would suggest you to go with SlickSlider. It is a robust, responsive and fast. It is also very very easy to customise and use.

Have a look at their website : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I took your codepen and inserted SlickSlider to it and here is the code for it. I understand that you are not really comfortable with jquery but there is not much to it. You just need to tell slick what is the container of your slider and then give it the options that you wish to change. There are various demos on their website to help you find the best option.

https://codepen.io/vikrant-icd/pen/QgKXmN

You only need this much jquery to enable the slider. Rest is all HTML and CSS. If you need more customisation, you can refer their website and give it a try. This is the best way to get used to jQuery, or any other language for that matter.

```
  $('#slides').slick({
    vertical: true,
    nextArrow: '<a href="#" class=" arrow slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>',
    prevArrow: '<a href="#" class="arrow slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>'
  });
```

I hope this helps. Please note that I have also cleaned the HTML a bit. Other than removing SlidesJS code, I have not added or changed anything else in your code.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked your codepen link. It looks like they are missing dots now as I have in my codepen and also I see two double up arrows in your codepen. Any idea what's wrong and how can we fix it?

Comment: And also I noticed, if I keep clicking up arrow many times, I saw blank form on the screen not sure why.

Comment: please have a look at the updated CodePen. I have added the bullets and solved rest of the issues. You can style the bullets the way you want.

Comment: just checked it.. yeah looks like that blank form problem is solved... in your case bullets are coming at the very bottom.. Is there any way it can be as the way it is in my question? If it can come to the place the way it is in my question just at the right center then it will solve all my issues.. Problem is in my codepen I tried a lot to center those dots as earlier I had lot of issues and when I was trying with your codepen, I was having issues while fixing that dots..

Comment: Thanks. Also, how can I make the dots look exactly same as https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwWZpV ?

Comment: At this moment, dots look pretty smaller in comparison to what I have in my https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwWZpV

Comment: you can modify the css to change the look of the bullets to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the SlidesJS plugin code and it looks like it doesn't have a direction option. All over the code it just changes the "left" offset so it doesn't seem like it will support it.

I would suggest either moving to another plugin or you will have to adjust the plugin manually from "left" offset to "top" (this will for sure require some CSS adjustments as well).

Comment: I see.. Do you have any recommendation which other plugin I can use here that can do orientation from top to bottom. I tried searching but I didn't find it. Or do you think its easy enough to modify this plugin to do the stuff that I am looking?

Comment: I have not come across any plugins like this as well. I have build a component that needs to work with both horizontal and vertical layouts in mind and at the end wrote everything myself - again with top or left offset based on the orientation. I do not think it will be too hard to make the adjustments if you are comfortable with jQuery and CSS3.

Comment: That is the thing I am not that much comfortable with jQuery yet. If you can help me out then it will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a different slider, [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com) has an option for this.

```js
$('#slides').bxSlider({
  mode: 'vertical',
  slideMargin: 5
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slides" class="container-fluid">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>FIRST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>LAST NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>COUNTRY</label>
        <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>PROVINCE</label>
        <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>CITY</label>
        <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will find your final thing at this point.

https://codepen.io/sahil_patel/pen/NgppqW

Updated code:

```
.slick-dots li button{
    display: block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 13px;
    background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
}

li.slick-active button{
    background-position: 0 -13px;
}
```

Thank you,
Sahil Patel